# Stash your request in elasticsearch cache with nest?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm working with nest and Elasticsearch and I would like to put a security measure for if there is a connection issue with a node. From what I could see there is a cache system that could store all format of information in the cache and retrieve it afterward. The issue is that I couldn't find many examples of implementation and don't really understand how it works.
Or did I get it totally wrong about the cache?

Is it possible to stash a request in the cache when a node is down?
If yes how do you get access to those informations?
If not is there another way I could use to do that?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a caching mechanism for requests in NEST, the .NET Elasticsearch client. There is a caching mechanism for serialization components, so that serialization is fast after the cache is primed, but these are internal implementation details.

Depending on the response returned for a given request and the type of [connection pool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/connection-pooling.html) that the client is configured with, a request may be [retried by the client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/retries-and-failover.html) on other available nodes.